# Crash when UIAlertView is clicked

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview

When I click the `UIAletView`, I receive the following error.

```
alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x84c7010
```

This is the code I have used.

```
    UIAlertView  *testAlert = [[ UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:messageTitle message:messageBody delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:messageClose otherButtonTitles:messageTryAgain, nil];
    testAlert.tag = 2;
    [testAlert show];
    [testAlert release];
```

And I have the delegate method

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

}
```

When I click the `UIAlertView` , even before the control reaches the delegate method, the app crashes. What could be the reason. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There seems to be a memory issue with the delegate. Is it released before presenting the alert?

Comment: I have tried autorelease. But that doesn't seem to be the issue. Even with that it seems the `UIAlertView` is being released prematurely.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the `UIAlertView`. The responder (self) is the one that is released too early.

Comment: So, what should be done here. When should I set the `UIAlertView` delegate to self

Comment: Remove release from your code and recheck...:)

Comment: @Umair_uas I assume you are talking about the release of the `UIAlertView`. I have checked that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**This is "one hack of a solution".**
Hopefully it helps you understand that your delegate is the memory issue. The delegete (in this case `self`) is deallocated somehow before the `testAlert` is dismissed

```
  // retain self to avoid crash you were experiencing earlier
UIAlertView  *testAlert = [[ UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:messageTitle message:messageBody delegate:[self retain] cancelButtonTitle:messageClose otherButtonTitles:messageTryAgain, nil];
testAlert.tag = 2;
[testAlert show];
[testAlert release];


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
  // release self because you've gotten past the crash
  [self release];
}
```

This is in no way an elegant solution and should encourage you to debug your app further to find out why `self` is being deallocated prematurely

Comment: How can I check whether self is being released. Is NSLog the right way?

Comment: @XaviValero It would be more clear if you put a breakpoint right before you show the alertview and type "po self" into gdb. Keep stepping through and typing "po self" to see when self is deallocated.  It wouldn't be a bad idea to throw NSLog(@"myClass deallocing"); in your dealloc method

Answer (score 2):

Just wondering, could you show us your .h file?

If I had to hazard a guess, you've forgotten to set your class to respond to UIAlertViews as a delegate

You might be missing something like this:

`@interface MyClass : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>`

Comment: Well, it was worth a shot, I guess. That's the thing I always forget.

Comment: even if you didn't set that it would run fine, only to rise a compiler warning

Answer (score 1):

If ARC enable UIAlertView Object retain and no need to release, it's automatically release your object.